# Karma Jasmine Angular Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Short version: When I run karma, angular is telling me it cannot inject my 'common' module.
The actual error is:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=common
```

Here's the details:

My Karma **test.js**

```
"use strict";

describe('Testing ModuleToTest',function(){
    beforeEach(module('ModuleToTest'));

    var $scope = {};
    var factory = {...make up stuff...}

    // inject - access angular controller 
    beforeEach(inject([
        '$controller','$rootScope',
        function($ctrl,$rs){
        $scope = $rs.$new();
        $ctrl('ModuleToTestCtrl',{
            $scope:$scope,
            CommonFactory:factory
        });
    }]));

    it('should define a someStuff object',function(){
        expect(testScope.someStuff).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

My **ModuleToTest** definition:

module.js file:

```
angular.module('ModuleToTest',[]);
```

controller.js file:

```
angular.module('ModuleToTest')
.controller('ModuleToTestCtrl',
['$scope','$http','CommonFactory',
function($scope,factory){
    $scope.someStuff = ['foo','bar'];
}]);
```

The module that defines the **CommonFactory**:

module.js file:

```
angular.module('common',[]);
```

CommonFactory.js

```
angular.module('common')
.factory('CommonFactory',['$http',function($http){
   // do factory stuff here
}]);
```

Application module defintion, app.js:

```
angular.module('MyMainApp',['ModuleToTest', ... , 'common']);
```

karma.config.js:

```
// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],//'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  {pattern: 'js/vendor/angular/*.js'},
  {pattern: 'js/common/*.js'},
  {pattern: 'moduleToTest/js/*.js'},
  {pattern: 'moduleToTest/*.html'},
  {pattern: 'js/*.js'},
  {pattern: 'index.html'},
  {pattern: 'test/test.js'}
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
  'js/vendor/bootstrap*.js',
  'js/vendor/jquery*.js'
],
```

Quick caveate: MyMainApp works as I expect it to.  I am just beginning to use Karma to build unit tests for my applications modules.  Eventually I will build the unit tests for MyMainApp, but I'm trying to start small.

Any suggestions or clarifications are welcome, in addition to answers!  Thank you!

**UPDATE**: After helpful responses (thank you by the way!)  In short, I'm getting the same error, but I've tried to simplify the problem.

I removed any mention of 'common' from my ModuleToTest.  And Karma is still complaining about 'common'.  Here's the details:

My Karma test.js

```
"use strict";

describe('Testing ModuleToTest',function(){
    var testScope = {};

    beforeEach(function(){

        module('ModuleToTest');

        inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
            testScope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller('ModuleToTestCtrl',{
                $scope: testScope
            }); 
        });
    });

    // No it statement for now because the module won't even load
});
```

My **ModuleToTest** definition:

module.js file (*notice no reference to CommonFactory*):

```
angular.module('ModuleToTest',[]);
```

controller.js file (*notice the removal of CommonFactory*):

```
angular.module('ModuleToTest')
.controller('ModuleToTestCtrl',
['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.someStuff = ['foo','bar'];
}]);
```

**ANSWER**: Given the simplified version, the solution was to put *angular-mocks.js* after *angular.min.js* in the *karma.conf.js* file.

I hope this saves somebody else the trouble.

Comment: This is because you are injecting `CommonFactory` in your controller which is a part of `common` module which is not yet injected in your tests. Remove CommonFactory injection to `ModuleToTestCtrl` any see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have "common" as a dependency to "ModuleToTest" as that is where its components are used, ie

```
angular.module('ModuleToTest', ['common']);
```

---

For your test, you should really be creating a mock `CommonFactory` for complete collaborator isolation.

```
describe('Testing ModuleToTest', function() {
    var testScope, CommonFactory;

    beforeEach(function() {
        CommonFactory = {}; // or whatever mock implementation you need

        module('ModuleToTest');

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            testScope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller('ModuleToTestCtrl', {
                $scope: testScope,
                CommonFactory: CommonFactory
            });
        });
    })

    // specs go here
});
```

Comment: Phil, I +1 your answer because it was helpful, but it didn't necessarily solve the issue.  I'm not sure if I should give it the green check or not.  Any advice on protocol here.  Thanks!

Comment: @westandy see how you go when you want to test the interaction between your controller and factory. You'll find having the factory as a test double will help immensely. You don't have to accept this answer (yet).

Comment: After building other tests without dependencies (or controllers), I came back to this, used your CommonFactory suggestion, and, let's just say, it worked like a charm.